# unsigned int vs signed int relevence in storing the value

Tags: c, types, unsigned-integer

Do `unsigned int`  and  `signed int` have any relevance as far as the storage is concerned. I know it has its relevance in a print statement i.e.; `-1`  will be treated as `4294967295` (`%d` and `%u`) . If we consider just storage of the value , does the `unsigned` or `signed` would make a difference?

Comment: *as far as the storage is concerned* - what do you mean by that? Are you asking if it will take different amount of space?

Comment: A 32-bit integer will always be 32 bits. Doesn't matter if it's signed or unsigned.

Comment: @EugeneSh, as far as "only" the storage is concerned. I meant if my intension is just to store the data.

Comment: *just to store the data* - what data? data has meaning. It can be signed or unsigned, numerical or textual, integer or real...

Comment: EugeneSh, integer

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. If the data is signed, it should be stored in format representing signed numbers. If it is unsigned, it should be stored as representing unsigned data. Because you want also retrieve it in some point and interpret as original. Do you have some specific problem/application which have motivated this question?

Comment: Franc M  False premise: "-1  will be treated as 4294967295 (%d and %u)" --> No, that is UB.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you cannot have a value without a type. (Various operations are defined in terms of mathematical values, but each operation is specified to produce a result in a particular type, so, at each point in a C expression where there is a value, it has a type.) So any value is stored by storing the bytes of the object that represents it.

The C 2018 standard specifies the representations of types in 6.2.6 and of integer types specifically in 6.2.6.2. Objects are composed of one or more bits. Unsigned integers are represented with pure binary plus optional padding bits. The order of the bits is not specified. For a signed integer type, one of the bits is a sign bit, and each value bit has the same values as the same bit of the corresponding unsigned type. Some of the value bits in the unsigned type may be padding bits (unused for value) in the signed type. (But the total number of bits is the same, per 6.2.5 6.) The sign bit either indicates the value is negated or it represents the value −(2<sup>*M*</sup>) or −(2<sup>*M*</sup>−1), where *M* is the number of value bits. (Which of those three is implementation-defined.)

Therefore, whether an integer type is signed or unsigned makes no difference regarding the interpretation of the common value bits. It affects only the interpretation of bits that are value bits in the unsigned type but a sign bit or padding bits in the signed type. (The latter are rare.)

If the value in a signed integer type is the same as the value in its corresponding unsigned integer type, they have the same value in each of their common value bits and zeros in all of their unshared sign or value bits. (The padding bits are not specified by the C standard.)

Comment: Since it's not entirely clear (at least to me) what the OP is actually asking, it may also be relevant that corresponding signed and unsigned integer types (such as `int` and `unsigned int`) are specified to occupy the same amount of storage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True about  same storage, yet large _unsigned_ types may have more padding such than `I..._MAX == UI..._MAX` - thus impacting the interpretation of  some bits as value, sign add/or padding.  I have not seen such dinosaurs for a long time.

Comment: Agreed, @chux-ReinstateMonica. I did not intend to imply different.